# Не вызывается метод __set() при использовании оператора &&

Tags: php, yii2

Есть такой метод:

```
/**
 * @param array $data
 * @return bool
 * @throws \yii\base\Exception
 */
public function trySave($data = [])
{
    if (
        $this->load($data) &&
        $this->validate() &&
        $this->unique_id = $this->getUniqueId() &&
        $this->password_hash =
            Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($this->password) &&
        $this->save(false)
    ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

При сохранени, `$this->save(false)` выдаёт исключение, что `unique_id` и `password_hash` не имеют значений по умолчанию, то есть они `null`.

Чтобы отдебажить это дело, я переписал метод так:

```
/**
 * @param array $data
 * @return bool
 * @throws \yii\base\Exception
 */
public function trySave($data = [])
{
    if ($this->load($data)) {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            if ($this->unique_id = $this->getUniqueId()) {
                if (
                    $this->password_hash =
                        Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash(
                            $this->password
                        )
                ) {
                    if ($this->save(false)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

И меня удивило то, что второй вариант заработал.

Не могу понять почему не устанавливаются атрибуты `unique_id` и `password_hash` в первом случае?

---

На данный момент выяснил, что в первом случае не вызывается метод `yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord::__set($name, $value)` при попытке записать значения в указанные аттрибуты:

```
// ...
$this->unique_id = $this->getUniqueId() &&
$this->password_hash =
    Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($this->password) &&
// ...
```

Comment: Добрый день. Я думаю, что проблема в другом. Да и свалка в условии if не очень хорошо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что дело в [приоритете и ассоциативности операторов](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). Судя по всему, с && ваш код воспринимается интерпретатором следующим образом:

```
if (
    $this->load($data) &&
    $this->validate() &&
    $this->unique_id = (
      $this->getUniqueId() &&
      $this->password_hash = (
        Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($this->password) &&
        $this->save(false)
      )
    )
) {
```

Поэтому unique_id и password_hash не устанавливаются, т.к. для их вычисления необходимо сначала выполнить `$this->save()`. У `and` более низкий приоритет, чем у `=` (в отличие от `&&`), как видно из таблицы по ссылке, что может повлечь за собой изменение порядка выполнения. **Тем не менее, я не смог это воспроизвести на своей машине - && правильно делил выполнение, и все ветки у меня выполнялись по очереди (возможно, все дело в различиях версии интерпретатора)**.

Как выше правильно заметили, всего этого бы не произошло, если бы вы не стремились положить в условие те вещи, которые к нему не имеют отношения. Гораздо проще было бы воспользоваться ранней терминацией:

```
public function trySave($data = [])
{
    if (!$this->load($data) || !$this->validate()) {
        return false;
    }
    $this->unique_id = $this->getUniqueId();
    $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($this->password);
    return $this->save();
}
```

Comment: **Золотые слова**: `если бы вы не стремились положить в условие те вещи, которые к нему не имеют отношения` )

Answer (score 0):

Всё дело в операторе `&&`: если заменить его на `and`, то первый вариант начинает работать.

```
/**
 * @param array $data
 * @return bool
 * @throws \yii\base\Exception
 */
public function trySave($data = [])
{
    if (
        $this->load($data) and
        $this->validate() and
        $this->unique_id = $this->getUniqueId() and
        $this->password_hash =
            Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($this->password) and
        $this->save(false)
    ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

У операторов `&&` и `and` есть [небольшие отличия в работе](https://php.net/language.operators.logical#80005).

<s>Если кто пояснит более подробно, то «милости прошу»; а пока это будет хоть каким-то, да ответом.</s>

Comment: Добрый день. Я думаю, что проблема в другом. Да и свалка в условии if не очень хорошо.

Comment: @slo_nik, согласен насчёт свалки, однако дело именно в работе оператора `&&`, так как если его заменить на `and`, то всё работает. Я полагаю, что это PHP-шный баг.

Comment: @slo_nik, так как сеттер-то должен был вызваться в любой случае, ведь таких свойств у класса нет.